# Can See Directory But Not Contents

Tags: ssh, ftp

I am using `Bitvise` to connect to a server and am able to see the directory C:\Testing but when I double click that directory to open it, it shows an empty directory.  However, on the server itself there are about 4 .txt files inside.

What is causing me to not be able to see the contents of this folder?  Looks like we don't have a dedicated tag for bitvise :/

**EDIT**
Upon @Frank Thomas suggestion below I checked a few settings.  I am logging in through the a virtual account that I created username of testuser and this is the account that can not see the contents of the directory.  If I log in with an actual user account on the server PC I can view full contents of the directory.

Comment: do you have read/list permission to the directory?

Comment: @FrankThomas - Windows does not have anything like that set up and Bitvise does not either.  The strange thing is, it worked perfectly last time I tried this (wednesday of last week) and now it is not.

Comment: no idea what you mean by `virtual account`. from windows perspective you have to be using a user account on the system, so whether there is a windows user called TestUser, or bitvise implements a differant scheme where virtual users impersonate a real account, the actual windows account being used by the process to access the files will need to have Read\List File permissions on the directory.